# _Layout.cshtml(16,22): error CS0103: The name 'HTML' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a simple MVC 4.0 website. I have choose empty project template. When i add layout page to the view folder's subfolder "Shared" and also add some code it gives error

"_Layout.cshtml(16,22): error CS0103: The name 'HTML' does not exist in the current context"

I have searched this one on the net but no solution could solve my problem.

Please help me out of this problem.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
             <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
             <link href="~/Content/GlobalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
             <style type="text/css">
             </style> 
                 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
                 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
         </head>
         <body>
             <div class="MainDiv">
                 <div class="MenuDiv">
                      <ul>
                         <li>@HTML.ActionLink("Home","Home")</li>
                         <li>About</li>
                         <li>Register</li>
                      </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div style="min-height:500px; width:70%; background-color:grey;                                                     vertical-align:middle;">
                     @RenderBody()
                 </div>
                 <div style="min-height:50px; width:100%; background-color:aliceblue; vertical-align:bottom;">
                     &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year
                 </div>
             </div>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `Html`, not `HTML`. C# and Razor are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<li>@HTML.ActionLink("Home","Home")</li>
```

with:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Home")</li>
```